# I get the same row duplicated as the result when I do a simple join using the laravel's DB facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-facade

**Code**

```
$result = DB::table('disaster_rescue_data')
    ->join('users', 'disaster_rescue_data.username', '=', 'users.email')
    ->get();
```

**Problem**

I have this very simple join as mentioned in the above code. However when I render the data on a view or `dd` the `$result`, I get the same row duplicated and I can not figure out why. (The rows contain the same data.)

(I am using Laravel 5.4)

Can someone please help me figure out why? (I tried different techniques and none of them worked! Thanks.)

Comment: I am using Laravel 9, same issue

Answer (score 0):

to prevent duplication, you should use [distinct](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct)() method, this method Returns only unique items from the result.

in order to do that, first you must stricly select what you want:

```
    $result = DB::table('disaster_rescue_data')
        ->select('disaster_rescue_data.*')
        ->join('users', 'disaster_rescue_data.username', '=', 'users.email')
        ->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: I tried this. But the result is the same. I only get the result. It gives me the result for the same row for all the records.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using distinct in the query. Distinct removes duplicates in a result set.

For example

```
$result = DB::table('disaster_rescue_data')
->distinct()
->join('users', 'disaster_rescue_data.username', '=', 'users.email')
->get();
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

EDIT:
Ok, I am thinking you can now use groupBy to get the unique results. Although it's not clear what your data structure is so this is a guess to use "users.email". Maybe it could be "disaster_rescue_data.username" to group by. Experiment and see.

```
$result = DB::table('disaster_rescue_data')
->distinct()
->join('users', 'disaster_rescue_data.username', '=', 'users.email')
->groupBy('users.email')
->get();
```

Comment: I tried this. But the result is the same. I only get the result. It gives me the result for the same row for all the records.